# ORA-06550: line 15, column 7:\nPLS-00103: Encountered the symbol &quot;BEGIN&quot;

Tags: php, oracle, stored-functions

i am trying to execute a stored oracle function in a package from a php script using a PHP Engine v5.1 and Oracle OCI extension module for PHP. And for that purpose i have 2 plsql block which will fetch the pk member_id and product_id and will be used in executing the function. In this process,i am getting the following error

> ORA-06550: line 15, column 7:\nPLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "BEGIN"

I am not sure how to resolve this error ?

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect("username","password","localdb");

$CONFIG_NAME='DirectType';
$BUS_SEG_CODE='';
$PRODUCT_NUM='130342';
$MEMBER_NAME='87307-3';
$EFFECTIVE_DATE=strtotime('2016-12-01');
$MODEL_DATE=time();
$CURRENCY='USD';
$REALM_NUM=1024;
$RESOLVED_PRICE=111;
$RESOLVED_CURRENCY='USD';

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection Successful"."\n";
    echo "System time is ".time();

   $sql_proc = "
   DECLARE
    v_MEMBER_ID NUMBER;
    v_PRODUCT_ID NUMBER;

  BEGIN
   SELECT cat_map_id INTO v_PRODUCT_ID
    FROM mn_cat_map WHERE product_num = :PRODUCT_NUM and catalog_type = 'INT';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Product Error');
    return;
  END;

  BEGIN
   SELECT member_id INTO v_MEMBER_ID
    FROM mn_member WHERE member_name = :MEMBER_NAME;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Customer Error');
    return;
  END;

   BEGIN PACKAGE_NAME.function_name(
   :CONFIG_NAME,
   :BUS_SEG_CODE,
   v_MEMBER_ID,
   v_PRODUCT_ID,
   :EFFECTIVE_DATE,
   :MODEL_DATE,
   :CURRENCY_CODE,
   :REALM_NUM,
   :RESOLVED_PRICE,
   :RESOLVED_CURRENCY
   );
   END;
   ";

   $stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql_proc);
   //  Bind the input parameter

   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':CONFIG_NAME',$CONFIG_NAME);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':BUS_SEG_CODE',$BUS_SEG_CODE);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':EFFECTIVE_DATE',$EFFECTIVE_DATE);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':MODEL_DATE',$MODEL_DATE);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':CURRENCY_CODE',$CURRENCY);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':REALM_NUM',$REALM_NUM);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':RESOLVED_PRICE',$RESOLVED_PRICE);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':RESOLVED_CURRENCY',$RESOLVED_CURRENCY);

  // Parse the statement. Note there is no final semi-colon in the SQL statement
    $result=oci_execute($stmt);

    if (!$result){
        $e = oci_error($stmt);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
        print htmlentities($e['message']);
        print "\n<pre>\n";
        print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
        printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
        print  "\n</pre>\n";

    }
    else {
        echo "Execute STMT returns True or False : ".$result;
        echo "Resolved Price is : ".$RESOLVED_PRICE. "\n";
    }
    echo "</pre>";
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
    oci_close($conn);
}
else {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in one block, not 3 separate blocks:

Change this:

```
DECALRE
...
BEGIN
...
END;
BEGIN
...
END;
BEGIN
...
END;
```

to this:

```
DECLARE
...
BEGIN
SELECT ..
SELECT ..
FUNCTION CALL ..
END;
```